# Rig veda 6.27.5

Tags: rig-veda

This is what Rig veda 6.27.5 says

> vadhīdindro varaśikhasya śeṣo.abhyāvartine cāyamānāya śikṣan |
> vṛcīvato yad **dhariyūpīyāyāṃ** han pūrve ardhe bhiyasāparo dart ||

Some claim that Hariyupiya refers to Harappan civilisation. Is this claim backed by commentary on this verse or by any scriptures like Puranas ?